# Cross-validation error threshold in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, interpolation, geostatistical-analyst, inverse-distance-weighted, cross-validation

I'm learning the Geostatistical Wizard toolset in ArcMap 10.4.1 and I am performing the cross-validation step in an IDW interpolation.

I have done some research regarding the process of cross-validation, however I can't find any information regarding the **threshold** of the **prediction error**
in the auto-correlation model.

What is the threshold of the prediction-error, which excludes sampling points in the auto-correlation model?